# iPad UISplitViewController view frame

Tags: ipad, view, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I wonder how I can change a splitView.view.frame ?

In my app I'm using a tabBarController to display differents splitViews by tab.
But I need to leave an empty space between my tabBar and my splitView to put another view.

I tried to change the splitView.view.frame but It doesn't work... any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Split View Controller section of the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW2),

> "The UISplitViewController class is a container view controller that
> manages two panes of information. The first pane has a fixed width of
> 320 points and a **height that matches the visible window height**.
> The second pane fills the remaining space."

So, I'd say you can't do it. But maybe someone else has a solution for this.

Word of advice, though: don't complicate your interface. Try and think of a better way to achieve what you are thinking of showing in that intermediate view. Maybe place it somewhere else or present it in some other way.

Comment: Thanks you ! My intermediate view is an advertising which format is very strict (1024*90 or 768*90) so I must place it on the top or bottom of the splitView, I have no choice...